# Replacing a letter from a string with that same letter in the same position in a list - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Python beginner and am having the hardest time making a basic hangman game.  I'm at the point where it is supposed to fill in the blanks when a correct letter is guessed.  Just looking for a simple beginner way to do this.
This is what I'm trying that is not working at the moment:

```
word = random.choice(word_list)
word_dis.append("*" * len(word))
for chtr in word:
     chtr_pos = word.find(current_guess)
     print(chtr_pos)
     if chtr == current_guess:
          word_dis[chtr_pos] = chtr
```

and I'm getting:

> ```
> list assignment index out of range
> ```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code dies at the first line on an undefined variable.

Comment: I *think* you want `word_dis = "".join([chtr if chtr == current_guess else word_dis[i] for i, chtr in enumerate(word)])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word = random.choice(word_list)
word_dis = list("*" * len(word))

num_guesses = len(word)
while(num_guesses > 0):
    current_guess = input("Enter your guess")
    chtr_pos = word.find(current_guess)
    if chtr_pos is not -1:
        word_dis[chtr_pos] = word[chtr_pos]
    num_guesses -= 1
    print(word_dis)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to have it as broken down as possible so you can piece together how to create this and make it your own.

```
word = 'random'
word = list(word)
blank = '-'*len(word)

while blank != ''.join(word):
    print(blank)
    letter = input('Enter a letter: ')
    if letter in word:
        x = word.index(letter)
        for idx, item in enumerate(blank):
            blank = list(blank)
            blank[x] = letter
            blank = ''.join(blank)
    else:
        continue

print('Congratulations! The word was {}'.format(''.join(word)))
```

I used a pre-selected word since I dont have your word list.

What you could do is make your word a `list` now it will have each letter with its own `index` from there we can make a `blank` place holder of the same lenghth.

Next we can make a loop that will continue until they match, here I used `''.join(word)` as the comparison to maintain the `list` version but still be able to compare.

Then we can take a `letter` guess and `if letter in word` then we can get the index of that letter from word `word.index(letter)`, with this index we can now `enumerate(blank)` which allows us to access the `item and index` and we can replace the corresponding `index` in a `list` version of `blank` and `''.join(blank` put it back together.

This process will continue until the two words match and then after the loop breaks we can print our `Congratulations`

Make this your own but this is just a template to get you moving, cheers!